# How do I get rid of the <h1>Search</h1> at the top of the search results page?

Tags: search

A customer of mine insists on having *Search Results* as a heading. I can set this on the block I have created using the [Custom search](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_search) module.

How do I get rid of the `<h1>Search</h1>` at the top of the search results page?

Comment: I update my answer take a look

Answer (score 0):

I suggest way three way

- Hide it with css ( set it to `display:none`)
- Remove it with simple Jquery command  ( `.remove`)
- override  search result page template

I mean **duplicate page.tpl.php file in your custom theme** set name to **page--search.tpl.php** and remove `<h1><?php print $title; ?></h1>`. **finally don't forget clear the cache**

If this TPL doesn't work then you have to declare it in `template.php` using `theme_hook_suggestions` in the same way as answer of your linked question. See for the URL which your instance is using for giving search result.

For `$base_url/search` use

```
//replace your theme name with MYTHEME
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) { 
  if (arg(0)=='search') {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__search';
  }
}
```

Add this in your `template.php` & as you are suggesting TPL for page, you have to use `THEME_preprocess_page($vars)`.

Comment: That `<h1>Search</h1>` is the page title, which is not added, nor altered by search-results.tpl or from its preprocess hooks.

Comment: @kiamlaluno It thought   `<h2><?php print t('Search results');?></h2>`, tnx for inform me, I change my answer.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I update it. tnx for you notice.

Comment: It's not `$node->title` since that is not a node page.

Comment: @kiamlaluno  yes, it is ` print $title` .

Comment: Thanks for this. In the end I used simple CSS to remove it. I had tried overriding the search result template, but the template containing the title was not made available for me to override.

Comment: @MagicLAMP your welcome, sometimes handle it with just a CSS or JQuery line save our time. ;)
you use one of my solutions :D . close the question please with mark answer.